# Install an app made for SUSE Enterprise 11 on openSUSE 11.4

Tags: kernel, opensuse

I'm trying to see if I can install Symantec System Recovery 2011 Linux edition on an openSUSE 11.4 system. According to the docs, SSR 2011 for Linux supports (among others) SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 and 11 SP1.

I downloaded the trial version, extracted it and ran a .bin installer but it failed with the error message, "Kernel (2.6.37.6_0.11_desktop) is not supported".

The 2.6.37 kernel appears to be the latest version as installed by Yast. So I'm wondering is it possible downgrade the kernel to match the one in SLES 11 SP1? Would doing that make Symantec System Recovery able to install? The kernel in SLES 11 SP1 is apparently 2.6.32.

Thanks